# Skipping levels in angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In Angular, is it possible for the ng-repeat directive to skip levels?

For instance, on a nested array like this :

```
     { id: 1, name: "A",
         children : [
         {id: 11, name: "AA",},
         {id: 12, name: "AB",
             children : [
                 {id: 121, name : "ABCA",
                 children : [
                     {id: 1211, name : "ABCAA"}
                 ]}
             ]}
        ]}
```

The only way I know of representing levels 3 or 4 would be by iterating over the earlier levels, something like:

```
<div class="level1" ng-repeat="level in levels">
    {{level.name}}
    <div class="level2" ng-repeat="level in level.children">
        {{level.name}}
        <div class="level3" ng-repeat="level in level.children">
            {{level.name}}
            <div class="level4" ng-repeat="level in level.children">
                {{level.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to skip x levels, and jump straight to the desired one using the directive ?

The above can be found here if its any helps: https://jsfiddle.net/gowkgv4q/

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is no, and that wouldn't even make sense if it were possible.  This seems to be an XY question, you seem to have something you want to accomplish, but this pseudo data doesn't give any clues to what it might be, and you are instead asking about a possible solution that doesn't make sense on it's own.

Comment: sure there is...map the data to whatever filtering or flattening you need first before passing it to the view. As pointed out you need to identify what the real issue is